# Django 403 Error When JS is Imported (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

When I have my javascript at the top of my HTML file, it runs flawlessly. However, I wanted to clean up my code by putting the javascript in the static/js folder, but when I move my javascript and import it (I know I am importing from the correct location), I get a 403 error when I try to use any of the ajax calls.

This way works:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
<script>
----------my javascript here--------------
</script>
```

This way gives me a 403:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/calc.js">
```

Here is the ajax call giving the error:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url : "/ajax_ad/",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
          'my_pk' : adValue,
        },
          success : function(json) { 
            myResults.innerHTML = "<p>"+json.make + "</p>
          },
          error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); 
          }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `myResults.innerHTML = "<p>"+json.make + "</p>` is missing a trailing `"` - Is that a copy paste error?

Comment: PROBLEM FIXED: 

Copied the code from schillingt's answer into a script, which I loaded before my original script, then followed metsfan's instructions and everything is running beautifully. 

(and yes the missed " was a copy paste error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you put the javascript into it's own file, you just serving it up with no context data, while your javascript has `{{ csrf_token }}` inside of it.

The 403 you're getting is Permission Denied. It's thrown whenever you make a POST with no csrf_token.

Django has some good documentation around how to handle this with ajax [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Here's the copied code from the docs.

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

You'll want to throw this into it's own file and load it before the other javascript file that makes a post to your web app.

Answer (score 1):

schillingt's answer gives the correct reason: Your Javascript file is static, and not processed by the template processor.

Here's an alternative I used: In my HTML template, outside a form. I put the CSRF token: `{% csrf_token %}`.

This puts an input in your HTML file: `<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='[csrf token will be here]' />`

In my Javascript (since you're using jQuery):

```
.ajax({ 
    url : "/ajax_ad/",
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    data : {
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
      'my_pk' : adValue,
    },
      success : function(json) { 
        myResults.innerHTML = "<p>"+json.make + "</p>
      },
      error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); 
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually care about CSRF protection, you can use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator on the view. You'd need this import for that: `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`.

Comment: thank you! this is fantastic to know. I'll vote up once i finally reach 15 reputation